# Exercises 7(b) and 7(d) on p.111 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres. Is my solution ok or not?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, continuity

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

I solved Exercises 7(b) and 7(d) on p.111.
But I am not sure my solution is ok or not.
Is my solution ok or not?

> Exercise 7 on p.111:
>
> Prove the following:
>
> **Theorem.** Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Let $D$ be the set of points of $S$ at which $f$ fails to be continuous. Let $E$ be the set of points of $\operatorname{Bd}S$ at which the condition $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=0$$ fails to hold. Then $\int_S f$ exists if and only if $D$ and $E$ have measure zero.
>
> Proof.
>
> (a) Show that $f_S$ is continuous at each point $x_0\notin D\cup E$.
>
> (b) Let $B$ be the set of isolated points of $S$; then $B\subset E$ because the limit cannot be defined if $x_0$ is not a limit point of $S$. Show that if $f_S$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $x_0\notin D\cup (E-B)$.
>
> (c) Show that $B$ is countable.
>
> (d) Complete the proof.

My solution is the following:

(b) Suppose that $f_S$ is continuous at $x_0$.
For any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that \begin{equation}|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f_S(x)-f_S(x_0)|<\varepsilon.\tag{1}\end{equation}
Assume that $x_0\in D$.
Then, $x_0\in S$.
So, $f_S(x_0)=f(x_0)$.
By (1), for any positive real number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that \begin{equation}|x-x_0|<\delta\text{ and }x\in S\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f_S(x)-f_S(x_0)|<\varepsilon.\tag{2}\end{equation}
So, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.
This is a contradiction since $x_0\in D$.
So, $x_0\notin D$.

---

Next, assume that $x_0\in E-B$.
By (1), if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ and $x\in S$, then $$|f(x)-f_S(x_0)|=|f_S(x)-f_S(x_0)|<\varepsilon.$$
So, $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f_S(x_0)$.
Since $x_0\in E$, $f_S(x_0)\neq 0$.

Since $x_0\in\operatorname{Bd}S$, if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n-S$, then $|f_S(x)-f_S(x_0)|=|0-f_S(x_0)|<\varepsilon$.
So, $f_S(x_0)=0$.
This is a contradiction.
So, $x_0\notin E-B$.

So, $x_0\notin D\cup (E-B)$.

---

(d) If $D$ and $E$ have measure zero, then $\int_S f$ exists by (a).
If $\int_S f$ exists, then $f_S$ fails to be continuous on a set which has measure zero.
So, by (b), $D\cup (E-B)$ has measure zero.
$B$ is countable by (c) and a countable set has measure zero.
So, $D\cup E=(D\cup (E-B))\cup B$ has measure zero.
So, $D$ and $E$ have measure zero.